# Обновление данных в dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Есть программа на win формах. На форме dataGridView. Используется база данных mssql. Модель базы создана с помощью code first. Вот мой класс(таблица):

```
class Systems
    {
        public int SystemsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот как я добавляю в него данные.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Context db = new Context())
            {
                Systems system1 = new Systems { Name = "Система 5"};
                db.System.Add(system1);
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.systemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDbDataSet.Systems);
            }
        }
```

Строчка `this.systemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDbDataSet.Systems);` должна обновлять гриду после добавления. Но этого не происходит. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Результат:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Context db = new Context())
            { 
                dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.ToList();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Context db = new Context())
            {
                Systems system1 = new Systems { Name = "Система 7"};
                db.System.Add(system1);
                db.SaveChanges();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.ToList();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Метод `Refresh` _перерисовывает_ компонент. Он не имеет никакого отношения к обновлению _данных_.

Comment: `TableAdapter.Fill` заполняет таблицу данными. Но датагрид об этом не знает. Да, нужно делать перепривязку.

Answer (score 1):

Тут у вас перемешка ADO и Entity, что в данном контексте не самое лучшее. Каким образом у вас строится связь с datagridview? Если через dbDataAdapter, то зачем? Это же Entity, а не Ado. Достаточно было бы привязать напрямую к списку System:

```
List<System> lst = db.System.ToList();
dataGridView.DataSource = lst;
```

При изменении System делай Refresh или Update dataGridView:

```
using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            Systems system1 = new Systems { Name = "Система 5"};
            db.System.Add(system1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

P.S. System - очень плохое имя для таблицы(да и вообще для чего либо), т.к. пространство имен уже зарезервировано с этим именем в C#. Если по контексту таблица связана с какими то системами, то лучше что то дописать. GameSystem, PictureSystem и т.д.

Попробуй так:

```
BindingList<System> lst;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Context db = new Context())
        { 
            List<System> dbList = db.System.ToList();
            lst = new BindingList<System>(dbList);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            Systems system1 = new Systems { Name = "Система 7"};
            db.System.Add(system1);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Метод `Refresh` _перерисовывает_ компонент. Он не имеет никакого отношения к обновлению _данных_.

Comment: Так ему и надо перерисовать элемент, т.к. данные уже изменились

Comment: В крайнем случае можно использовать не List, а BildingList

Comment: @ValeryLosev я привязываю данные к гриду с помощью конструктора. То есть в визуальном представлении гриды в правом верхнем углу выбираю выпадающий список и добавляю там новый источник данных. Или так не совсем корректно?

Comment: Корректно, но это очень устарело и использует технологию ADO.NET. Смысл в том, что вы привязываетесь к базе через одну технологию, а изменяете данные через другую. И удивляетесь, почему эти технологии о друг друге не знают. Если используете ADO, то необходимо добавлять по другому, через DataSet.

Comment: @ValeryLosev сделал как вы сказали, только немного изменил и пришлось добавить ещё строчку при сохранении, что мне не очень понравилось, сейчас покажу что. Изменённый код в вопросе.

Comment: @ValeryLosev приходится каждый раз при сохранении вот эту вот строчку использовать `dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.ToList();`

Comment: Т.е. я каждый раз во всех кнопках должен гриду указывать откуда ему брать данные?

Comment: Нет, привязка только в Form1_Load
Сейчас перепишу, как лучше сделать

Comment: Повторяю: `Refresh` в данном контексте **бесполезен**!